# Multiple graphic objects from method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphic

I had a task to draw checkers board. Here is my frame class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class AppFrame extends JFrame {
    public AppFrame() {
        setTitle("Kółko i kwadracik");
        setSize(1000, 1500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        initGUI();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabPane.addTab("Plansza", new PlanszaGry());
        tabPane.addTab("Obrazek", new PanelZObrazkiem());
        tabPane.addTab("Wykres", new Wykres());
        tabPane.addTab("Warcaby", new Warcaby());
        tabPane.addTab("4 Warcaby", new Warcaby4());

        add(tabPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Than a class to create single checkers board, it's the one new Warcaby()

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Warcaby extends JPanel {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Stroke defaultStroke = g2.getStroke();

        int y = 9; // tu ustawiamy liczbę linii (czyli w sumie wilekość planszy)

        // linie planszy do gry
        for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
            float dash[] = { 10.0f };
            Stroke lineStroke = new BasicStroke(3.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                    BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
            g2.setStroke(lineStroke);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            int x = i * 100;
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(100 + x, 100, 100 + x, 100 * y));// linie
                                                                        // pionowe

            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(100, 100 + x, 100 * y, 100 + x)); // linie
                                                                        // poziome

        }

        // Plansza do gry (czarne/białe pola)
        for (int a = 1; a < y; a++) {
            if (a % 2 != 0) {
                for (int b = 1; b < y; b++) {
                    if (b % 2 == 0) {

                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                        g.fillRect(b * 100, a * 100, 100, 100);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int b = 1; b < y; b++) {
                    if (b % 2 != 0) {

                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                        g.fillRect(b * 100, a * 100, 100, 100);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My next task is to draw 4 boards next to eachother, teacher gave me a hint to create method drawing one board with information about it's position. I can't figure it out how to even start. I've start with this:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Warcaby4 extends JPanel {

    public void Warcaby(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        super.paint(g);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Stroke defaultStroke = g2.getStroke();
        float dash[] = { 10.0f };
        Stroke lineStroke = new BasicStroke(3.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
        g2.setStroke(lineStroke);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {

            x = i * 100;
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(100 + x, 100, 100 + x, 100 * y));// linie
                                                                        // pionowe

            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(100, 100 + x, 100 * y, 100 + y)); // linie
                                                                        // poziome

        }

        // Plansza do gry (czarne/białe pola)
        for (int a = 1; a < y; a++) {
            if (a % 2 != 0) {
                for (int b = 1; b < y; b++) {
                    if (b % 2 == 0) {

                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                        g.fillRect(b * 100, a * 100, 100, 100);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int b = 1; b < y; b++) {
                    if (b % 2 != 0) {

                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                        g.fillRect(b * 100, a * 100, 100, 100);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now I don't know where and how call out it 4 times, am I even doing it right? Please give me some suggestions. :)

Comment: TL;DR. Consider moving this to the code review stack exchange.

Comment: @MadPhysicist _. I can't figure it out how to even start_ <- code must be already written

Comment: Next sentence: *I've start with this*

Comment: @MadPhysicist A start isn't enough. It should work in the capacity OP wants it to. Code Review doesn't do feature requests.

Comment: @MadPhysicist if I write half a program, the program is not already written nor fully working. See: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Why not add you `Warcaby` component to a `GridLayout` and add four instances of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My next task is to draw 4 boards next to eachother, teacher gave me a hint to create method drawing one board with information about it's position. I can't figure it out how to even start. I've start with this:

Why not just re-use the component you already have?  For example, using a `GridLayout` you could just create as many components as you need...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class AppFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AppFrame();
    }

    public AppFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
                frame.add(new Warcaby());
                frame.add(new Warcaby());
                frame.add(new Warcaby());
                frame.add(new Warcaby());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Warcaby extends JPanel {

        public Warcaby() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

//            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int horontialPadding = insets.left + insets.right;
            int verticalPadding = insets.top + insets.bottom;

            int width = getWidth() - horontialPadding;
            int height = getHeight() - verticalPadding;

            int size = Math.min(width, height) / 10;

            int xOffset = insets.left + ((width - (size * 10)) / 2);
            int yOffset = insets.top + ((height - (size * 10)) / 2);

            for (int vertical = 0; vertical < 10; vertical++) {
                for (int horzontial = 0; horzontial < 10; horzontial++) {
                    int x = horzontial * size;
                    int y = vertical * size;
                    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    if (vertical % 2 == 0) {
                        if (horzontial % 2 == 0) {
                            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    } else if (horzontial % 2 != 0) {
                        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    g2.fillRect(xOffset + x, yOffset + y, size, size);
                }
            }
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawRect(xOffset, yOffset, size * 10, size * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I optimised your drawing code, now it can resize based on the available space.

Also, you should NEVER update the state of the UI from within any paint method (like calling `setBackground`), this is a very bad idea which could lead into an infinite paint loop which would consume your CPU cycles and render your system unusable (yes, I've done this)

As a general rule of thumb, you should prefer `paintComponent` over `paint`.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Thanks for tips, I just started learning graphics.  Your code looks really advanced compared to mine, hehe :)

Comment: Not really, it's the basic concept of what you already did, I just made it more "variable", but that's because I wanted to control the size of the board's better.  The basic concept of using a `GridLayout` should work for you code (but you'll want to pay attention to the `getPreferredSize` ;))

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to finish this task on my own. Here's the code in case someone will have similar problem.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        rysujWarcaby((Graphics) g, 50, 50);
        rysujWarcaby((Graphics) g, 50, 500);
        rysujWarcaby((Graphics) g, 500, 50);
        rysujWarcaby((Graphics) g, 500, 500);

}

public void rysujWarcaby(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        int xx = 1;
        int nr = 9;
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Stroke lineStroke = new BasicStroke(3.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                        BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
        g2.setStroke(lineStroke);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {

                xx = i * 50;
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x + xx, y, xx + x, y + 50 * 8));

                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x, y + xx, x + 50 * 8, y + xx));

        }

}
```